# Could anyone test and criticize my automaton simulator?

Tags: cs-theory, turing-machines

My name is David Buzatto and I am a teacher of several subjects on a Computer Science course. One of these subjects is Theory of Computation and, this semester, I decided to implement a simulator of finite automata, pushdown automata and Turing machines, with the aim of using it instead of the already known JFLAP. I would like if, if possible, someone could test it and critique the current version of the tool. Why? Well, my biggest concern is: does it work as expected? It is very difficult to test for possible corner cases. Although JFLAP is the "standard", I think this tool is a little complicated to use in some points, especially in relation to the construction of state machines. I tried to create something more user friendly.

The current tool features are:

### Finite Automata (FA)

- Full support for Deterministic and Nondeterministic Finite Automata modeling, test and simulation;
- Create, edit, save and save as image;
- Support to add all missing transitions;
- Support for removal of inaccessible and useless states;
- Conversion from Nondeterministic Finite Automaton to Deterministic Finite Automaton;
- Deterministic Finite Automaton minimization;
- Regular Operations:

  - Union;
  - Concatenation;
  - Kleene Star;
  - Complement;
  - Intersection.

### Pushdown Automata (PDA)

- Full support for Deterministic and Nondeterministic Pushdown Automata modeling, test and simulation;
- Create, edit, save and save as image;
- Conversion from Final State to Empty Stack and vice-versa acceptance types.

### Turing Machines (TM)

- Full support for Deterministic Turing Machines modeling, test and simulation;
- Support for Nondeterministic Turing Machines modeling;
- Create, edit, save and save as image;
- Automatic detection of infine loops, i.e., Turing Machines that never halt.

You can download it here https://github.com/davidbuzatto/YAAS/releases/tag/v1.0.1

Best regards!

Comment: Are there any aspects of the project you are most interested in testing or getting feedback about? What are the benefits of using a new tool instead of the existing standard JFLAP?

Comment: @ggorlen My biggest concern is: does it work as expected? It is very difficult to test for possible corner cases. Although JFLAP is the "standard", I think this tool is a little complicated to use in some points, especially in relation to the construction of state machines. I tried to create something more user friendly. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Are PDA transitions editable after they are made?  I can't figure out how.

Comment: @BenI. Yes they are! Just use the move tool (little hand) and either click on the transition and edit it in the panel on the right (button with a pencil) or right click in the desired transition and choose de option "Operation(s)" on the popup menu.

Comment: @davidbuzatto Oh, I see! I've started raising issues on github for you.

Comment: @BenI. thank you very much! I'll wait a few days to start working on them. Best regards!

Comment: dummy suggestion: why wouldn't you do some proper testing?